# Comparing Prices from Two Online Supermarkets using Web Scraping in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am working on a program to compare prices of similar products from two online supermarkets using Python. I have two URLs representing the product pages from each supplier, and I need to extract and compare the prices of the given products.
URL's are:
`laughs_coconut = 'https://scrape-sm1.github.io/site1/COCONUT%20market1super.html'`
`glomark_coconut = 'https://glomark.lk/coconut/p/11624'`

I have started working on a `compare_prices` function, but I'm facing some challenges in extracting and comparing the prices. I would appreciate any guidance or improvements on the existing code.

I have attempted to implement the `compare_prices` function by inspecting the structure of the HTML pages and using web scraping techniques. I expected the function to correctly extract and compare the prices of the given products.

Comment: You can improve your question by including the existing code you would like help with.

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask] and related articles for guidance on asking good questions. Also see: [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405791/what-should-a-minimal-reproducible-example-include-for-problems-with-automati) A scraping question needs a representative HTML sample in your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example implementation of the compare_prices function using these libraries:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_price(url):
    # Send a GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the HTML content of the page
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        
        # Find the element containing the price
        price_element = soup.find('span', class_='price')  # Adjust this according to the structure of the page
        
        # Extract the price text
        if price_element:
            price_text = price_element.text.strip()
            # Some cleaning of the price text, e.g., removing currency symbols
            # You may need to customize this part based on the structure of the page
            price_text = price_text.replace('Rs', '').replace(',', '').strip()
            return float(price_text)  # Convert the price to a float
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch page:", url)
    return None

def compare_prices(url1, url2):
    price1 = get_price(url1)
    price2 = get_price(url2)
    
    if price1 is not None and price2 is not None:
        if price1 < price2:
            print("Product from laughs_coconut is cheaper.")
        elif price1 > price2:
            print("Product from glomark_coconut is cheaper.")
        else:
            print("Prices are the same.")
    else:
        print("Unable to compare prices.")

# URLs of the product pages
laughs_coconut = 'https://scrape-sm1.github.io/site1/COCONUT%20market1super.html'
glomark_coconut = 'https://glomark.lk/coconut/p/11624'

# Compare prices
compare_prices(laughs_coconut, glomark_coconut)
```

- The get_price function fetches the HTML content from the given URL and then uses BeautifulSoup to parse the content and extract the price information. You might need to adjust the find method arguments according to the structure of the HTML on the product page.
- The compare_prices function uses the get_price function to retrieve prices from both URLs and then compares them.

Make sure to adapt the code to the actual structure of the HTML pages you're dealing with. You might need to inspect the HTML structure of the product pages to determine the appropriate way to locate and extract the price information.